# Probability increments

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Say you have three boxes and one of them has a ball in it. Box A has 50% probability to have the ball in it while the other two (Box B and Box C) have 25% probability each. If you open Box C and find that it doesn't have the ball in it, how does this increase the probability for the remaining two boxes? I presume Box A now has a probability of 66.7% while Box B has 33.3% probability. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that's right.  One way to intuit this is to imagine that $A$ is really two boxes, each of which has a $25\%$ chance of holding the ball.  After $C$ is removed, we'd then have three equally likely boxes, two of which happen to comprise $A$.

Comment: This looks like a variation of the Monte Hall problem.